# Why isn't my Spring Security config not permitting access?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a very simple example that I am working with.

A RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/unsecured")
public class UnsecuredController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }

}
```

and a class with my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/unsecured/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I want localhost:8080/unsecured/hello to be accessible and everything else blocked (I have other controllers with basic String returned).

What am I missing here?  I am using the spring boot spring-boot-starter-security 3.1.1, which pulls in spring security 6.1.1.

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:6.1.1:compile
```

Thanks

Comment: please enable DEBUG logs and update your question with debug logs. Also include what the actual error message is and what is happening than just writing "i cant access" which is a terrible way of describing what problems you have.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Just had to understand more how it works. I find that the docs aren't very intuitive.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/unsecured/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().denyAll()) // deny everything except for the above
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to separate the access types by creating different `SecurityFilterChain` beans.

Below is an example of your `ResourceServerConfig`  class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig {


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> { authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
                }).authenticationManager(new CustomAuthenticationManager());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> { authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/unsecured/**").permitAll();
                });
        return http.build();
    }  
}
```